# AngularJS $http.jsonp cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I am having trouble caching a JSONP request.

I have tried `$http.jsonp(url, { cache: true })` and it doesn't appear to be working.

I also tried `$http({ method: 'JSONP', url: url, cache: true })` to no avail.

Instead, I've resorted to manually caching the results (very very rough working example below).

Is it possible for AngularJS to do this caching for me?

```
countries.factory 'Wikipedia',
  ['$http', '$q', ($http, $q) ->
    cache = {}

    getSummary: (country) ->
      if cache.hasOwnProperty(country)
        cache[country]
      else
        summary = $q.defer()
        url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&rvparse=1&titles=#{country}&format=json&redirects=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK"

        $http.jsonp(url).success (data) ->
          # process data ....
          paragraphs = ['p1', 'p2']

          # return summary content paragraphs
          cache[country] = paragraphs
          summary.resolve paragraphs

        summary.promise
  ]
```

Comment: by "not working" you mean you see multiple requests in your inspector? Got a repro fiddle/plnker?

Answer (score 2):

As of version 1.0.7/1.1.5 it looks like `$http` only supports caching for GET method requests.

- [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1947) is a link to an open github issue about it.
- [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1548) is a closed pull request with some additional information.

The caching section for the [$http documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) only mentions GET requests as being cached.